# Add a 'destroyAll' action and route to my RESTful rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, model-view-controller

I want to add a destroyAll action that destroys all posts in a blog app that I am writing. I have my routes.rb like this :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :writings
  root "writings#index"
end
```

And inside my controller I want to add the following action :

```
def destroyAll
  @writing = Writing.all
  @writing.each.destroy
end
```

please guide me through how to add a route to the destroyAll action and how to use it inside my view to make a link to use that action.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: you have a bug, `@writing.each.destroy` wrong and raise error

Comment: what should I replace it with, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be defined as collection route of `writings`:

```
resources :writings do
  collection do
    delete :destroy_all
  end
end
```

Having it, you can link to `delete_all` action like this:

```
link_to 'delete all', [:destroy_all, :writings], method: :delete
```

You should notice that I wrote `delete_all` instead of `deleteAll`, because the former sticks to Ruby naming convention.

Comment: One more thing Marek, is my action correct? @writing.each.destroy ?

Comment: Nope. It's gonna give undefined method `destroy` for AR collection error (or similar). You can use `destroy_all` method for this purpose: `@writings = Writing.all`, `@writings.destroy_all`.

Answer (score 1):

I think Marek Lipka's answer is perfectly adequate, but I'd like to offer an alternative, which IMO is a tad bit more RESTful. I'd model the collection of all `writings` as a separate resource. Since this resource does not have an id and there can only be one instance of this resource, it must be a singular resource:

```
resource :writings, only: :destroy
```

The problem with this is, that Rails will map this action to `WritingsController#destroy`, since Rails uses plural controllers for singular resources (any our singular resource has a plural name anyway), so this will conflict with the `destroy` action for individual writings. In that case you could either create a custom controller for this and implement a destroy action there:

```
resource :writings, only: :destroy, controller: 'collections/writings'
```

or you could still use the old controller, but specify another action:

```
resource :writings, only: :destroy, action: :destroy_all
```

In that case, you could use the following in your views:

```
link_to 'delete all', writings_path, method: :delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party, but wanted to add that perhaps another way is to consider **all of the writings** as a kind of resource itself, so you can keep the controllers adhering to the basic RESTful actions Rails typically uses.

```
resource :writings_collection, only: :destroy
# DELETE /writings_collection --> WritingsCollectionController#destroy
```

The advantage is the route helpers will not conflict with the `writings` ones.
You could even name the collection resource something meaningful that represents the collection concept.